# Prove that the real vector space consisting of all continuous, real-valued functions on the interval [0,1] is infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

A follow up to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519303/prove-that-the-real-vector-space-consisting-of-all-continuous-real-valued-funct). I kinda understand that the vector space of polynomials (P(R)) is a subspace to the  infinite set of numbers between the interval [0,1]. Is this because we can represent an arbitrary number within the interval with polynomial of any degree?
Something I am missing here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to further clarify the question. I'm guess i am trying to better understand the relationship between polynomials and the infinite interval [0,1]. @Community

Comment: Start by trying to understand what this vector space of "all continuous, real-valued *functions* on $[0,1]" **is**. What are the elements? What are the operations? Addition? Scalar multiplication?

Comment: The set of polynomials with real coefficients on $[0,1]$ is a subspace of the real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$, $C([0,1])$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra implies that the sequence $p_n(t)=t^n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ is linearly independent.